# Error in PREIN scriptlet in rpm package

Tags: rpm, oracle

I'm stuck with a problem when I try to install a local `.rpm` packages.
Error message:

```
Total size: 124 M
Installed size: 124 M
Is this ok [y/d/N]: y
Downloading packages:
Running transaction check
Running transaction test
Transaction test succeeded
Running transaction
error: Couldn't create temporary file for %pre(PACKAGE): Success
Error in PREIN scriptlet in rpm package PACKAGE
  Verifying  : PACKAGE                                                 1/1

Failed:
  PACKAGE
```

I'm completely lost, since I'm pretty new with linux.
I'm testing on a:
OS: `"Oracle Linux Server 7.9"`
Kernel release: `5.4.17-2136.309.4.el7uek.x86_64`

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to know WHY you get this failure because we don't have the SPEC.

RPM files are built from a SPEC file. A SPEC contains information about the package and instructions on how to install it. SPEC files also contain scriptlets (see https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/packaging-guidelines/Scriptlets/) that are triggered during different phases of the (un)installation.

If you have the source RPM (SRPM) of your local package, you can check the SPEC file and specifically the `%pre` scriptlets to see what's going on there. Use a command like `rpm2cpio my-local-rpm.src.rpm | cpio -civ '*.spec'` or use the Midnight Commander trick from below.

If you don't have the SRPM, a simple trick to view the scriptlets is to install Midnight Commander (`mc`) by issuing `sudo yum -y install mc`, then run `mc` and go to your RPM. Press Enter on the filename. Navigate to `INFO/SCRIPTS` and check the contents of the different scriptlets by pressing F3.